# dynamic SVG with file.css

Tags: css, xml

[Level Crossing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSZHB.png)

I want to create a Level Crossing Dynamic by css. The deafult point is the first image. In the ST-01 i want the 2nd image and at the ST-02 i want the 3rd image.

```
<g transform="translate(50 150) scale(1.2 1)" class="Box-ST00" stroke="none" fill="none">
    <rect width="150" height="10"/>
</g>
<g transform="translate(90 30) scale(1.2 1) rotate(90)" class="Box-ST00" stroke="none" fill="none">
    <rect width="150" height="10" transform="scale(1.2 1) rotate(-50)" />
</g>
```

with file.css as follows :

/* Box STATE00 - None */
.Box-ST00 {
stroke: black; fill: black; stroke-width: var(--boxes_stroke_width_small)
}

/* Box STATE01 - White */
.Box-ST01 {
stroke: white; fill: white ; stroke-width: var(--boxes_stroke_width_small)
}

I tried in this way and i obtain only the Level crossing completely filled or not.
Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot I'm not really sure about the shape you want to obtain. But at first I would delete your transform *scale style* (because I don't see the point) and the attributes you want to redefined on CSS side (*stroke* & *fill*).
I also changed the colors in order to distinguish stroke and fill and then I put "1px" to the stroke-width style instead of your css var because it was not defined in your sample.

So it would be something like this :

```
<svg>
  <g transform="translate(100 140)" class="Box-ST00">
    <rect width="150" height="10"/>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(90 150) rotate(0)" class="Box-ST00">
    <rect width="150" height="10" transform="rotate(-90)" />
  </g>
</svg

<style>
  .Box-ST00 { stroke: black; fill: #ccc; stroke-width: 1px }
  .Box-ST01 { stroke: black; fill: #ccc ; stroke-width: 1px }
</style>
```